# code contracts with dynamic variables

Tags: c#, .net

Sample code:

```
    private dynamic tableAdapter; 
    public dynamic TableAdapter 
    {
        get
        {
            return tableAdapter;
        }
        set
        {
            tableAdapter = value;
            if (tableAdapter != null)
            {
              SQLiteConnection cn = tableAdapter.Connection;
            }
        }
    ...
```

After build i have warning: *CodeContracts: reference use unreached (1 more unreached assertion(s) at the same location).*
 May be there is some way to solve problem without change tableAdapter type into object?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with CodeContracts. The problem is due to using Dynamic variables which seems reasonable, as the static checker cannot reach the available fields or methods of a dynamic object. My approach was to suppress the warning.